# Drupal 6 Slideshow with Drupal Views Cycle module

Tags: drupal-6

[image: no file type available]

I'm trying to follow how to set up a slide show in drupal 6 using the following website:
http://blog.echopx.com/2010/03/slideshow-with-drupal-views-cycle-module/
but there is no 'file' type under manage fields and I'm wondering why that is, since there should be.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you do not have any of the contrib Modules filefield or imagefield installed.

- https://drupal.org/project/imagefield
- https://drupal.org/project/filefield

Install these modules and activate them. Then you will see new field type options on the `Manage fields` tab.